# PHP and MySQL always inserts 0 for a column

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I insert something into the second column in the database (uname) it ends up being 0. I debugged it and it has the correct text in php. Even if I hard code a value like "joe" it still inserts 0 in MySQL. The column is varchar(16). I also tried type Text. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw", "db");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$enteredUsername = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, uname, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $enteredUsername, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the select results from the database and show the table definition?

Comment: siss means casting the second var as integer

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your bind parameters from int (`i`) to string (`s`):

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $enteredUsername, $age, $password);
```

Comment: Presumably it was intended to be `ssis` to get `age` as an integer.